# Formulae for energy of photon (E=hf and E=hv)

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation

I have seen the energy of a photon given by the formulas:

$$E = h \cdot f \tag{1}$$ 
Where $E$ = energy of the photon, $h$ = Planck's constant, $f$ = frequency of radiation [(Source: BBC article)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/higher/physics/radiation/optoelectronics/revision/1/)

I've also seen it given as

$$E= h \cdot \nu \tag{2}$$ 
Where $\nu$ stands for frequency [(Source: Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation)

But in this topic I've also seen

$$f=\nu/\lambda \tag{3}$$ 
Where $\nu$ = speed, $\lambda$ = wavelength [(Source: Simple English Wikipedia article)](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency)

**Is there any difference between equation 1 and equation 2? And is equation 3 unrelated?**

Comment: If you're talking photon energy with the Planck equation, you should be using $c$ for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion. They all are actually the same formulas. It is because lets start with the first equation,

$$E=h \cdot f$$

But we know that frequency can be written in terms of speed formula,
$$ v = f \cdot \lambda$$

Which can be rearranged into the following,
$$ \frac{v}{\lambda} = f $$

If you put that expression into the above equation, then that becomes

$$ E = f \cdot \frac{v}{\lambda}$$

Hence the same formula can be written in many ways.

---

Your first two equations are just the same. $f$ usually stands for frequency and in the second equation you have just used $\nu$ for it. That is the frequency of the *photon* that is coming in or being released.

Whereas your third equation actually comes from the speed formula as I have written above,
$$ v = f \cdot \lambda$$

Rearranging for frequency, you get:
$$ \frac{v}{\lambda} = f $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MathCurious314 :) So is it just a matter of v standing for different things in E=Hf and v=f*lambda? And the first two formulas are exactly the same?

Comment: There is much extra in this answer, but fundamentally, author correctly points out that it is the same equation.  Take heed orthoCresol's comment in question

Comment: @K-Feldspar exactly. $v$ is being used for frequency in the second while it is being used for velocity in the third. :)